# Python: Creating an array with multiple dimensions given the shape

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to figure out; given that

`x.shape = (6,4,3,2)`
and
`y.shape(3,2)`

What would be the shape of `numpy.maximum(x,y)`?

However, I'm not sure how to recreate the variable **x**. I'm able to recreate **y** pretty easily, but I've never dealt with 4 dimensional shape like `x.shape` before. I was wondering if someone could help me out.

Thank you!

Comment: `numpy.random.randint(0,255,(6,4,3,2))` is how i would do it if i wanted to create it ... but i think the goal of this exercise is to know the answer not generate the array

Comment: It most definitely is! But I wanted to recreate the array in my notebook in order to run numpy.maximum(x,y).shape in order to see what it would be. But yes, that definitely worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you don't really care what's in the array, just that you have an array.  `np.zeros((6,4,3,2))` would give you an array initialized to 0s.  `np.ones(...)` would give you an array of ones.  `np.empty(...)` gives you a completely uninitialized array filled with whatever happened to be in those memory locations before.